# Quitting a job before the relocation reimbursement contract expires

Tags: relocation

I have recently accepted a job with a company that has paid me to move to relocate to another state. The terms are if i quit the job before a year of employment, I will have to repay the relocation amount they have paid me.

How to professionally deal with this situation?

Will the employer file a suit against me? What are the repercussions?

Comment: Are you planning on leaving or are you just saying "what if you did, what would happen?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to leave a job without paying back relocation?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64009/is-it-possible-to-leave-a-job-without-paying-back-relocation)

Comment: If you're still in negotiation with the new employer, tell them about the money you'd be required to repay. If they want to hire you before that date comes up, they may be willing to match that amount for you.

Answer (score 3):

> I have recently accepted a job with a company that has paid me to move
> to relocate to another state. The terms are if i quit the job before a
> year of employment, I will have to repay the relocation amount they
> have paid me.
>
> How to professionally deal with this situation?

I assume there's nothing to deal with at this point in time.

You accepted their terms of employment already, so going forward the professional thing to do is to either stay for a year, or repay the relocation amount upon leaving earlier.

> Will the employer file a suit against me? What are the repercussions?

They may well sue you. I worked for one company that had similar relocation terms. They did sue an employee who left after 3 months. That's the only time I know of where an employee refused to return the money. All others acted professionally.

This won't be a worry at all if you just abide by the terms you signed. And obviously, if you didn't want to abide by those terms you should have refused the relocation pay or negotiated some other arrangement. That's the way to remain professional.

Answer (score 0):

If you signed the contract that says:

> relocation expenses are reimbursed to the company if employees works less than a year

then you have to pay whatever bill they will send you.

We don't know the answer to "Will the employer file a suit". We also don't even know whether such contract would be legal - that is for lawyer to advise.

What we know is that

1. quitting job for whatever reasons is OK
2. honoring contracts is generally good idea

If you don't pay back, even if they don't sue you for breach of contract, it might seriously mar your reputation.